# "Cannot load NSManagedObjectModel. nil is an illegal URL parameter"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I want to get the managed object context from AppDelegate, but the app crashed after I put the two lines of code into the method even I did nothing else, and there was a message in debug area:**"CoreData: Cannot load NSManagedObjectModel.  nil is an illegal URL parameter..."**

The code added in my method:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext;
```

-managedObjectModel method in AppDelegate:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
// The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
    return _managedObjectModel;
}
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"FoodPin" withExtension:@"momd"];
_managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
return _managedObjectModel;
}
```

and  the -managedObjectContext method:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
// Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.)
if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (!coordinator) {
    return nil;
}
_managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

**"FoodPin" is my project name**.So what's wrong here?I'm new to iPhone programming (Core Data in particular).

Can anyone help me?

Thanks...

Comment: The problem is this `[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"FoodPin" withExtension:@"momd"];` is returning nil into `modelURL`. Do you have a Core Data model named FoodPin in your project?

Comment: Oh..thanks a lot, I forgot to alter my name of .xcdatamodeld file!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"FoodPin" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

`modelURL` is `nil` meaning that the system couldn't find the resource `FoodPin.momd`.

Make sure you have a Core Data model in your project named `FoodPin`. It will appear as `FoodPin.xcdatamodeld` in the Project Navigator.

Comment: NOTE: Even though the file appears with extension `xcdatamodeld`, the method should still be looking for extension `momd` (as it is in the code in this answer).

Comment: Even though I have the file the file in my project with same name, I get the same error.

Comment: @ChanchalRaj Any solution so far ?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem but for me the modelURL was correctly set. The problem was that my *.xcdatamodeld file was not in the Copy bundle ressources anymore. I don't know why it disappear but to add it again fix the problem.

Here is how to fix it :
You project > Build Phases > Copy Bundle ressources > "+" button and select you xcdatamodeld file

Comment: This solved my problem. I wonder what happened. Looking at my commit history, the *. xcdatamodeld was never in the Copy Bundle Resources build phase. I'm using Xcode 8 beta 6.

Comment: I removed the *. xcdatamodeld from the Copy Bundle Resources build phase, and the problem remains solved. Probably a caching issue with Xcode, which means that doing a Clean or Clean Build Folder might solve this issue for others.

Answer (score 0):

NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"XYZ" withExtension:@"momd"];

Make sure your data model name match with URLForResource:XYZ.

Answer (score 0):

OK here's what I had to do.  I had reverted by iOS version back to 9.x in order to run on an older iPad I have.  This caused the error as prior versions must be case-sensitive in the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

try "mom" instead of "momd"

NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"name" withExtension:@"mom"];

Comment: Your suggestion fixed my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same error.

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"name" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

"n" in name had to be "N": like everything else in obj c this mother is case sensitive.